# How to get particular row data on click of edit icon ReactJS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Hi I'm using bootstrap table and used to display some data.

Example :

[image]

How can i get particular row data when i click edit icon?

**Code :**

```
<table className="table table-striped table-custom">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td style={tableStyle}>Date</td>
        <td style={tableStyle}>Bill No</td>
        <td style={tableStyle}>Amount</td>
        <td style={tableStyle}>Edit</td>
        <td style={tableStyle}>Delete</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    {this.state.customerIndividual.map(para => {
        return <tr key={para.id}>
            <td>{para.date}</td>
            <td>{para.billNo}</td>
            <td>{para.amount}</td>
            <td>
                <button className="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onClick={this.editMode} data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit">
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button className="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onClick={this.editMode} data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete">
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    })}

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind some unique identifier of each row with `onClick` function, whenever you click on edit button you will get that value, use that value to get the data from state array.

Value that you can use as unique identifier `index, id, amount, date etc`.

Write it like this:

```
{this.state.customerIndividual.map((para, i) => {
    return <tr key={para.id}>
        <td>{para.date}</td><td>{para.billNo}</td><td>{para.amount}</td>
        <td><button onClick={this.editMode.bind(this, i)} ..... </button></td>
        <td><button onClick={this.editMode.bind(this, i)} ..... </button></td>
    </tr>;
})}
```

Write `editMode` like this:

```
editMode(index, event){
    console.log('item index = ', index);
    //data = this.state.customerIndividual[index];
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you ,, but having doubt that how can i get that in a function?                                 editMode = (e) => { e.preventDefault(); } // here

Comment: now arrow function with editMode is not required, because i bound it inline, check the answer use the `editMode` function as i suggested it will work :)